# Problem with XslCompiledTransform and xslt in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, xslt, xslcompiledtransform

I am getting now where with this. I have an XML document that must be transformed using an xslt sheet. My code is as follows:

```
        Dim xStream As New IO.MemoryStream

        ' Create the XslCompiledTransform and load the stylesheet.
        Dim xslt As New XslCompiledTransform()
        xslt.Load(strLKxsl)

        ' Create the XslCompiledTransform and load the stylesheet.
        Dim xslt As New XslCompiledTransform()
        xslt.Load(strXSLfolder & "xslt_lookup.xslt")

        ' Create the XsltArgumentList.
        Dim xslArg As New XsltArgumentList()

        Using w As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(xStream)
            ' Transform the file.
            xslt.Transform(xmldLookup, Nothing, w)
        End Using
```

I get the following error at the xslt.Transform(xmldLookup, Nothing, w) line:

*Token StartElement in state EndRootElement would result in an invalid XML document. Make sure that the ConformanceLevel setting is set to ConformanceLevel.Fragment or ConformanceLevel.Auto if you want to write an XML fragment.*

This is the contents of the XMl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="includes/xslt_lookup.xslt"?>
<lookup xmlns="logis-online:lk"
title="<Document Title>"
nexturl="<URL>">

  <search visible="false">
    <field id="SUPPLIER_NO" hidden="true" size="10"
    value="<Value>" />
    <field id="WEB_STORE_NO" hidden="true" size="10"
    value="<Value>" />
    <field id="REST" hidden="true" size="40" value="" />
    <field id="LOOKUP_ACTION" hidden="true" size="1" value="<Value>" />
    <field id="WEB_ACTION" hidden="true" size="2" value="<Value>" />
  </search>
  <results>
    <header>
      <section>
        <item id="SUPPLIER_NO" title="Supplier No" value="<Value>"
        HelpID="10" />
        <item id="SUPPLIER_NAME_SHORT" title="Supplier Name"
        value="<Value>" HelpID="10" />
        <item id="LIABLE_STORE_NO" title="Liable Store No"
        value="<Value>" HelpID="98" />
      </section>
    </header>
    <list target="<lookup aspx page>" />
  </results>
</lookup>
```

Comment: I assume `title="<Document Title>"` is not really in your XSLT, you have something like `title="ABC"` - right?

Comment: Please show us the stylesheet code, we need to see any `xsl:output` instructions at least. Do you want a plain text file or an HTML document or an XML document as the transformation result?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably caused by your XSLT code creating some output that is not a well-formed XML document but only a fragment, probably having several top level elements. That is possible with XSLT and if you simply write to a file or stream you shouldn't have any problems. Your code, for reasons you have not explained, constructs an XmlWriter over a MemoryStream, and by default any XmlWriter created with XmlWriter.Create(stream) checks that any output is a well-formed XML document and throws an exception if not.
So to avoid the problem you either don't create an XmlWriter at all and simply do

```
xslt.Transform(xmldLookup, Nothing, xStream)
```

or you create an XmlWriter with the OutputSettings of the XslCompiledTransform instance e.g.

```
Using xw As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(xStream, xslt.OutputSettings)
```

Comment: THX alot marting and dimitre. took me alot of time to find this post and some more time to understand u 2, so here is an idiot proof explanation http://bresleveloper.blogspot.co.il/2013/07/how-to-use-xslcompiledtransform-xslt-in.html

Answer (score 0):

This message is self-explanatory. It means that the result of the XSLT transformation is not a well-formed document and in order to force the XmlWriter to write such a thing, its ConformanceLevel setting must be set/specified as either `ConformanceLevel.Fragment` or `ConformanceLevel.Auto`. Read more about "Data conformance nad the XmlWriter" **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50f80zbz.aspx)**.

If the XSLT transformation is not intended to produce an XML document, it is better not to specify an XmlWriter for producing the result. A better choice would be a to use a **[Transform() overload that accepts a TextWriter argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163435.aspx)**.

Otherwise, you could simply write directly to a stream (not specifying any XmlWriter).

Or, **[create an XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162617.aspx)** using the appropriate **[XmlWriterSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.aspx)** (specify `ConformanceLevel.Fragment` or `ConformanceLevel.Auto`).

Or, if the XSLT transformation must produce an XML document -- debug and fix it.